# Javascript, remove parameters from links

Tags: javascript, replace, trim

What I am trying to do is to create a small Chrome extension that will automatically trim the `&bar=` parameter from a list of links

So a link such as:

```
http://www.website.com/page&foo=2&bar=3
```

Becomes:

```
http://www.website.com/page&foo=2
```

Alternatively a solution where just copying the links will remove the `&bar=` parameters will do.

Comment: The query portion of a URL starts with `?`, not `&`

Comment: have a look into regular expressions http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace`, for example:

```
var s = 'http://www.website.com/page&foo=2&bar=3';
s.replace(/&bar=[^&]*/, "");
```

Comment: Maybe `*` is better: `/&bar=[^&]*/`.

Comment: @VisioN: Indeed, thanks, it's possible that `bar`'s value is empty.